# Sitecore 8 Multisite Experience Analytics

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms, sitecore8

I have a multisite Sitecore site I am working with and I have some question regarding analytics and marketing tools. Lets says I have CorporateSite, SubSiteA, and SubSiteB for ease of explanation.

Knowing that, the content tree would look like the following:

```
- CorporateSite.com
  + Content

- subSiteA.CorporateSite.com
  + Content

- subSiteB.CorporateSite.com
  + Content
```

Now, lets say I have users that correspond to each site:

```
CorporateJoe = CorporateSite Admin, SubSiteA Admin, SubSiteB Admin
SubSiteAJoe = SubSiteA Admin
SubSiteBJoe - SubSiteB Admin
```

CorporateJoe would have full access to the following:

- Marketing Control Panel
- Experience Analytics
- Experience Profile

CorporateJoe could create campaigns, view analytics, run reports, etc.
SubSiteAJoe and SubSiteBJoe should have the same rights but only for their site.

I know I can handle security for content and nodes using roles, users, etc, but how can I allow administrators of each multisite to utilize the marketing tools and analytics only for their site? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is currently possible.

Site name is recorded as a field on xDB visits, and later on it is included as a part of dimension keys in the Reporting Database. But then it is up to the reporting UI (xAnalytics, xProfile, etc.) whether to use SiteName for filtering or grouping the results of their queries. Security-wise, this is not something that is provided out of the box.

I am fairly positive that you could fine-tune xAnalytics queries to filter by SiteName, although it definitely sounds like too much of a hassle and not entirely what you need.